# tar contents in current directory to stdout

Tags: tar, stdout

I am trying to tar the current directory and stream to stdout (ultimately to Amazon S3)...I have this command:

```
tar  -cf -  .
```

but I get this error:

> tar: Refusing to write archive contents to terminal (missing -f
>   option?) tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

from what I can tell -f - means the file is to stdout, although `-f /dev/stdout` is probably more explicit.

does anyone know how to form the command correct?

Comment: Presumably you don't *really* want to stream the archive to your terminal - likely you will find that if you pipe it to another process it will be happy (for example, `tar -cf - . | tar -tf -`)

Comment: Have you tried `tar -cf - . > /path/file.tar`?  `/path/` can be anywhere so long as it is outside of `./`

Comment: why wouldn't it work to stream to the terminal though? seems weird that this would fail but -f /dev/stdout would work

Comment: It does work on FreeBSD and Mac OS X, fwiw.  But I can understand why the authors of `tar` might have thought it would be a relatively unlikely use case.

Comment: output to your terminal wiil be a bunch of gibberish at best or just crash your terminal program.  if you want to save it on S3, output it to a file first, and save the file with `aws s3 cp <filename> s3://<bucketname>/<prefixinbucket>`.  or do as i do and just backup with `aws s3 sync ...`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like many programs, `tar` checks to see whether its output is going to a terminal device (tty) and modifies its behavior accordingly. In GNU `tar`, we can find the relevant code in `buffer.c` :

```
static void
check_tty (enum access_mode mode)
{
  /* Refuse to read archive from and write it to a tty. */
  if (strcmp (archive_name_array[0], "-") == 0
      && isatty (mode == ACCESS_READ ? STDIN_FILENO : STDOUT_FILENO))
    {
      FATAL_ERROR ((0, 0,
                    mode == ACCESS_READ
                    ? _("Refusing to read archive contents from terminal "
                        "(missing -f option?)")
                    : _("Refusing to write archive contents to terminal "
                        "(missing -f option?)")));
    }
}
```

You will find that once you connect stdout *to* something, it will happily write to it:

```
$ tar -cf- .
tar: Refusing to write archive contents to terminal (missing -f option?)
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

whereas

```
$ tar -cf - . | tar -tf -
./
./001.gif
./02.gif
./1234.gif
./34.gif
```

Answer (score 3):

A gratuitous `cat` will work, also:

```
$ tar -cf - . | cat
```

Comment: you made me bing image search for "gratuitous cat"

Answer (score 0):

Another tricky approach: use `/dev/fd/1` or `/dev/stdout` as the output file:

```bash
$ tar -cf /dev/fd/1 .
```

However I am not sure about whether this solution is general.